# TS - Map id to object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm creating an app in React which has a multiple input fields - each field component has a unique id:

```
interface IFormInput {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    address: string;
    born: Date;
    etc..
}

const [input, setInput] = useState<IFormInput>(initialValues);

const onTextFieldChange = (id: string, newValue: string) => {
    switch(id) {
        case "0": setInput({...input, name: newValue}); break;
        case "1": setInput({...input, surname: newValue}); break;
        //etc..
    }
}
//...
<TextField id={"0"} onChange={onTextFieldChange} label={"Name"}/>
```

Is there any other smart way how to avoid all these long switch statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by given the corresponding object key to the input id like:

```html
<TextField id="name" onChange={onTextFieldChange} label={"Name"} />
<TextField id="surname" onChange={onTextFieldChange} label={"Surname"} />
...
```

Then the value of `id` parameter in `onTextFieldChange` function will be the key of your state object, so you can update it using this notation:

```js
const onTextFieldChange = (id: string, newValue: string) => {
    setInput({ ...input, [id]: newValue});
}
```

Here is the full example:

```js
interface IFormInput {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    address: string;
    born: Date;
    etc..
}

const [input, setInput] = useState< IFormInput >(initialValues);

const onTextFieldChange = (id: string, newValue: string) => {
    setInput({ ...input, [id]: newValue});
}
...
<TextField id="name" onChange={onTextFieldChange} label={"Name"}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass key to handler

```
const onTextFieldChange = (key: keyof IFormInput, newValue: string) => setInput(i => ({ ...i, [key]: newValue }));

<TextField onChange={value => onTextFieldChange("name", value)} label="Name" />
<TextField onChange={value => onTextFieldChange("surname", value)} label="Surname" />
```

Comment: Huh I didn't know it works this way too. What if I edit it to:
```const key = Object.keys(input)[parseInt(id)]; setInput({...input, [key]: newValue});```

Comment: @LuciCastle I think the answer below is better for you